# Integral with infinity limit and cosh

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

I have to compute this integral $$\lim_{\beta \to \infty} \frac{2 \beta J}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-h^2/2\beta^2}\frac{1}{\cosh^2(h)}\,dh$$
I have tried to use the L'Hôpital's rule and doing some manupulation replacing $\cosh(h)= \frac{e^{h}-e^{-h}}{2}$, but i don't seem to get the answer right.

Comment: What are the limits on the integral?

Comment: from -inf to +inf

Comment: This $e^{-x^2}$ reminds me of a statistics integral or an error function. Can you write out the cosh function in terms of exp(x) again so one can combine the bases?

Comment: What is the context of this integral, by the way? It looks like you’re averaging $E(\cosh(H)^{-2})$ when $H$ is Gaussian but its not quite exactly the same as your integral.

Comment: it's a condition used in the random field ising model (statistical physics) to describe transition at zero temperature

Comment: Are you certain that $\beta$ is a multiplicative factor here since $h/\beta$ is dimensionless?

Comment: i took the integral from the lecture notes of my professor

Comment: As $\beta\to \infty$, the integral tends to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sech}^2(h)\,dh=2$.  So, with the multiplicative factor $\beta$, the limit of interest is $\text{sgn}(J) \infty$.

Comment: i have to show that 2J= rad(pi/2) when this integral is equal to 1

Comment: Then almost assuredly, the factor of $\beta$ does not belong.

Comment: But the way it's derived it's 100% correct he derives tanh and 2BJ is the factor inside the argument

Comment: Do you understand that $\lim_{\beta\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-h^2/2\beta^2}\text{sech}^2(h)\,dh=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{\beta\to \infty} e^{-h^2/2\beta^2}\text{sech}^2(h)\,dh=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sech}^2(h)\,dh=2$?

Comment: yes, i think that's right but i don't get how to use the factor B before the integral

Comment: That factor is erroneous.  It has to be so.  In fact, without the multiplicative factor of $\beta$, if $J=\sqrt{\pi}/8$, then the limit is $1$, which is exactly what you need to show!

Comment: Why do you clog your question by including the irrelevant $J$?  Do you really need the $2/\sqrt{2 \pi}$ to ask the question?

Comment: Yeah, i think you are right that must be a typo of my professor.

Comment: Not a "typo," just an irrelevancy.  Simplify your question by including only the needed parts.  You'll more likely solve it on your own, and you'll certainly get more help.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You have not read all of the previous comments.  The factor $J$ is something that the OP needs to show is equal to $\sqrt{\pi/8}$ in order for the limit to be $1$.  The "typo" is the extraneous factor of $\beta$ (it does not belong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is assuredly a typographical error in the class notes and the multiplicative factor of $\beta$ outside the integral does not belong.

Let $I(\beta)$ denote the integral

$$\begin{align}
I(\beta)=\frac{2J}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-h^2/2\beta^2}\text{sech}^2(h)\,dh
\end{align}$$

Appealing to the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\beta\to \infty}I(\beta)&=\lim_{\beta\to \infty}\frac{2J}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-h^2/2\beta^2}\text{sech}^2(h)\,dh\\\\
&=\frac{2J}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{\beta \to \infty}e^{-h^2/2\beta^2}\text{sech}^2(h)\,dh\\\\
&=\frac{2J}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sech}^2(h)\,dh\\\\
&=\frac{4J}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
\end{align}$$

If $J=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$, then we have

$$\lim_{\beta\to \infty}I(\beta)=1$$

as was to be shown!